# Regex to find a digit and double quote in a Snowflake table row

Tags: javascript, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find records that contain a digit followed by double quote or followed by space and double quote in a snowflake table. Could you please tell me the regex to find all such records in a table?

```
6"
7 "
Hi
```

The regex should return 6" and 7 "

Comment: Please be aware that you are expected to show some attempts to resolve the issue by yourself when you ask something (see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/14201528) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html) will suffice:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(c TEXT)
AS SELECT '6"'
UNION SELECT '7 "'
UNION SELECT 'Hi';

SELECT * FROM t WHERE RLIKE(t.c, '\\d[ ]{0,1}["]');

-- anywhere in the string
SELECT * FROM t WHERE RLIKE(t.c, '.*\\d[ ]{0,1}["].*');
```

Comment: Thank you, Lukasz. The above regex doesn't seem to pick up values like ```TEST 4"``` and ```TEST 5 " ```

Comment: @vvazza The original question didn't mention that the check could be done anywhere in the string. but it could be easily extended `SELECT * FROM t WHERE RLIKE(t.c, '.*\\d[ ]{0,1}["].*');` Are multiple digits or decimal place allowed too? `TEST 22"` or `TEST 2.2 "`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Could you please explain what your regex mean? Especially {0,1} part. This was very helpful

Comment: @vvazza .* any character regardless of count, \\d digit single one, [ ]{0,1} space zero or one, ["] - single "

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very much appreciated :)